# Odd issue running iPhone image picker app on an iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, photo

Here's an odd issue I encountered running my iPhone app on my iPad. In this app I have an ABPersonViewController which I've subclassed in order to style it. When a user goes to this screen on an iPad, and attempts to add a new photo for the contact, they are shown a modally presented photo picker. This is normal.

But once they select a photo, another screen is pushed on the navigation stack of the photo picker with just the image, "Move and Scale" as the title, and cancel and choose text near the bottom.

Is this a bug running an iPhone app on an iPad? Because I know that you need to present photo pickers in a popoverController on the iPad.

When I try to do the same using the native contacts app, the move and scale screen is shown inside the popover. Anybody else encounter this?

Comment: I'm confused, `another screen is pushed on the navigation stack of the photo picker` and `move and scale screen is shown inside the popover` looks to be the same behavior for me.

Comment: When you add a photo on the native iPad app, a popover is used. But I'm running an iPhone app on an iPad, and iPhones do not support popovers natively. So the photo picker is shown instead modally.

It seems when this case is encountered on an iPad running an iPhone app, the screen that shows after picking the photo is messed up.

Comment: how is it messed up ? I'd expect the picket to behave the same way both with iPhone and iPad at 'sandboxed' mode and it seems to match what you are describing.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention. Nothing on the screen is clickable, and the user cannot exit the screen. The screen looks half rendered.